# I wrote a code to upload file using spring mvc.not showing any errors or warning but still getting 404 error after compiling it

Tags: spring-mvc

I wrote this code to upload file in a directory named images. But every time i run it on my eclipse using apache tomcat 7 it gives me HTTP Status 404 - /Fileupload/. I am using maven plugin in my eclipse to build the spring framework. It always gives Build success. Then while compiling with apache and running on my server there is this http error 404. I have attached all the jsp codes and xml codes along with this question. Please help

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.upload</groupId>
  <artifactId>Fileupload</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

HelloController.java

```
 package com.upload;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;  
import java.io.File;  
import java.io.FileOutputStream;  

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;  

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;  
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;  
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;  
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile;  
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;  
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
@EnableWebMvc
@Controller  
public class HelloController {  
    private static final String UPLOAD_DIRECTORY ="/images";  

    @RequestMapping("uploadform")  
    public ModelAndView uploadForm(){  
        return new ModelAndView("uploadform");    
    }  

    @RequestMapping(value="savefile",method=RequestMethod.POST)  
    public ModelAndView saveimage( @RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile file,  
           HttpSession session) throws Exception{  

    ServletContext context = session.getServletContext();  
    String path = context.getRealPath(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY);  
    String filename = file.getOriginalFilename();  

    System.out.println(path+" "+filename);        

    byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();  
    BufferedOutputStream stream =new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(  
         new File(path + File.separator + filename)));  
    stream.write(bytes);  
    stream.flush();  
    stream.close();  

    return new ModelAndView("uploadform","filesuccess","File successfully saved!");  
    }  
}
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"    
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"   
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"    
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context    
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">  
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />  

<context:component-scan base-package="com.upload"></context:component-scan>  

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
<property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>  
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>  
</bean>  

<bean id="multipartResolver"   
class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>  

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0"   
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"   
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">  
 <servlet>  
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>  

    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>  
<servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

index.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="uploadform.jsp">Upload Image</a>  
</body>
</html>
```

uploadform.jsp

```
    <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>  

<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
 <head>  
 <title>Image File Upload</title>  
 </head>  
 <body>  
<h1>File Upload Example </h1>  

<h3 style="color:red">${filesuccess}</h3>  
<form:form method="post" action="savefile" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
<p><label for="image">Choose Image</label></p>  
<p><input name="file" id="fileToUpload" type="file" /></p>  
<p><input type="submit" value="Upload"></p>  
</form:form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: try with @RequestMapping(value="/savefile",method=RequestMethod.POST)

Comment: also in your jsp <form:form method="post" action="/savefile" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: @cralfaro the code still showing the same 404 error page not found

Comment: Are you using some context path? also when the server starts check the logs, usually list in the console all controllers endpoints